# Replace all instances of a string in XML with ****

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a XSL that needs to filter out specific data found in the XML.

Somewhere in my XML there will be a node like:

`<id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1" extension="9494949494949" />`

The XSL I have below deletes the **extension** node and adds a **nullFlavor="MSK"** to the node.

What I need to do now, is take the value from the extension node, and search the entire XML document for that value, and replace it with ****.

But I'm not sure how to take the **extension** attribute, and find all instances of that value in the XML (they could be burried in text and inside attributes) and turn them into ****  (4 *).

The example below is just an example. I cannot hard code the XSL to look at specific nodes, it needs to look through all text / attribute text in the xml (reason for this is there are 5+ different versions of XML that this will be applied to).

I need to find the Extension in the  node, then replace (delete really) that value from the rest of the XML. I'm looking for a 1 solution fits all messages, so a global search->wipe of the Extension value.

Example:

```
        <identifiedPerson classCode="IDENT">
                <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1" extension="9494949494949" displayable="true" />
                <addr use="PHYS">
                    <city>KAMLOOPS</city>
                    <country>CA</country>
                    <postalCode>V1B3C1</postalCode>
                    <state>BC</state>
                    <streetAddressLine>1A</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>2A</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>9494949494949</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>4A</streetAddressLine>                        
                </addr>
                <note text="9494949494949 should be stars"/>
```

Should be (The below XSLT already masks the extension in the  node with the matching OID).

```
            <identifiedPerson classCode="IDENT">
                <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1" nullFlavor="MSK" displayable="true" />
                <addr use="PHYS">
                    <city>KAMLOOPS</city>
                    <country>CA</country>
                    <postalCode>V1B3C1</postalCode>
                    <state>BC</state>
                    <streetAddressLine>1A</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>2A</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>****</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>4A</streetAddressLine>                        
                </addr>
                <note text="**** should be stars"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I am able to use XSL 2.0

I have the current XSL.IT works fine. It matches any  tag where the root is '2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1', kills all attributes and adds a nullFlavor="MSK". However, this will not search the entire XML for that same #.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="attrToKeep" select="'root'" />

    <xsl:template match="* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="../@root = '2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1'">
          <xsl:copy-of select=".[contains($attrToKeep, name())]" />     
          <xsl:attribute name="nullFlavor">MSK</xsl:attribute>
          <!-- Need some way to use the value found in this node and hide the extension -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a variable to hold the value of the text to be replaced. Like this:

```
<xsl:variable
    name="rootVar"
    select="//*[@root = '2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1']/@extension" />
```

And then you should just be able to use the `replace` function to replace them.

```
<xsl:template match="'//@*' | text()">
    <xsl:sequence select="replace(., $rootVar, '****')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Works fine for finding and replacing within text. What would have to happen for attributes?

Comment: Change the template to match //@* | text()  and it works great!

Comment: Hmm, seems the update I put in match="//@* | text()", deletes all the attributes and puts the values inside the actual xml nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT 2.0 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="replacement" select="'****'"/>

  <xsl:param name="new" select="'MKS'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="identifiedPerson">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()">
        <xsl:with-param name="to-be-replaced" select="id/@extension" tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="identifiedPerson//text()">
    <xsl:param name="to-be-replaced" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="replace(., $to-be-replaced, $replacement)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="identifiedPerson//@*">
    <xsl:param name="to-be-replaced" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="replace(., $to-be-replaced, $replacement)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="identifiedPerson/id">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="nullFlavor" select="$new"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="identifiedPerson/id/@extension"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<identifiedPerson classCode="IDENT">
        <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1" extension="9494949494949" displayable="true" />
        <addr use="PHYS">
            <city>KAMLOOPS</city>
            <country>CA</country>
            <postalCode>V1B3C1</postalCode>
            <state>BC</state>
            <streetAddressLine>1A</streetAddressLine>
            <streetAddressLine>2A</streetAddressLine>
            <streetAddressLine>9494949494949</streetAddressLine>
            <streetAddressLine>4A</streetAddressLine>                        
        </addr>
        <note text="9494949494949 should be stars"/>
</identifiedPerson>
```

with Saxon 9.4 into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><identifiedPerson classCode="IDENT">
                <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1" displayable="true" nullFlavor="MKS"/>
                <addr use="PHYS">
                    <city>KAMLOOPS</city>
                    <country>CA</country>
                    <postalCode>V1B3C1</postalCode>
                    <state>BC</state>
                    <streetAddressLine>1A</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>2A</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>****</streetAddressLine>
                    <streetAddressLine>4A</streetAddressLine>
                </addr>
                <note text="**** should be stars"/>
        </identifiedPerson>
```

So for the sample it solves that problem I think. I am not sure whether there can be more context around that sample and whether you want to change values outside of the `identifiedPerson` element as well or don't want to change them (which above stylesheet does). If other elements also need to be changed consider to post longer input and wanted result samples to illustrate and also explain what determines the node where the value to be replaced is found.

[edit]
Based on your comment I adapted the stylesheet, it now has a parameter to pass in a id (e.g. `2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1`), then it looks for an element of any name with a `root` attribute having that passed in id value and replaces the `extension` attribute value found in all attributes and all text nodes found in the document. Furthermore a `nullFlavor` attribute is added to the element with the id and its `extension` attribute is removed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="root-id" select="'2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="to-be-replaced" select="//*[@root = $root-id]/@extension"/>

  <xsl:param name="replacement" select="'****'"/>

  <xsl:param name="new" select="'MKS'"/>

  <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:sequence select="replace(., $to-be-replaced, $replacement)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="replace(., $to-be-replaced, $replacement)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@root = $root-id]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="nullFlavor" select="$new"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@root = $root-id]/@extension"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The document format is not set in stone, so I can't hard code the XSL to search for specific nodes. It needs to check all of them for the correct value found in the OID mentioned (2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.6.1). i'll update the quesiton